# Solving Second Oder IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I am trying to figure out a way to solve the following IVP;

$y’’+y’+y=\sin^2t$

I am just really stuck on what to do with the $\sin^2t$ so any help would be so much appreciated thank you!

Comment: First solve the homogeneous equation $y''+y'+y=0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please tell us what you have tried and what you know about the problem. What knowledge do you have about second order differential equations with constant coefficients?

Comment: Hi I know a little bit I’m only very new to the concept. Im familiar with characteristic equations and y=yu+yd. For example, if the above equation only equalled sin(t), I would be fine I think solving the IVP. I just haven’t solved one like this before.

Comment: This is not an IVP, because you have a differential equation only.

Comment: Hint: $\sin^2 t = \frac12 - \frac12 \cos(2t)$. Then use the method of undetermined coefficients.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First Solve the Homogeneous Equation
$${y''+y'+y=0}$$ the solution have the form $y=e^{mt}$; then we have ${m^2+m+1}$ solve for m
$${m_{12}={-1\ \pm\sqrt{1-4(1)(1)}\over 2(1)}}$$
$${m_{12}={-{1\over 2}\pm{\sqrt3\over 2}i}}$$
$${y=e^{m_{12}t}\rightarrow{e^{\left({-{1\over 2}\ \pm \ {{\sqrt3\over 2}}i}\right)t}}}$$
$${e^{\left({-{t\over 2}\ \pm\ {{\sqrt3\over2}\it}}\right)}=e^{{-{t\over 2}\ }}e^{\pm \left({\{\sqrt3\over2}t\}\right) i}}$$
Recall Euler's Formula $\star\ \mathbf{e^{\pm\space i\theta}=cos(\theta)\pm\space i\ sin(\theta)}.$
Finally we have our Homogeneous Solution
$$\mathbf{y_{h}(t)=e^{{-{t\over 2}\ }}\left[C_{1}cos\left({\sqrt3\over2}t\right)+C_{2}sin\left({\sqrt3\over2}t\right)\right]}$$

For the Particular Solution $y_{p}=sin^2(t)$ replace it with $y_{p}={1+cos(2t)\over2}$.
By Undeterminated Coefficientes our has the form 
$$y_{p}= A+B\ cos(2t)+C\ sin(2t)$$
$$y'_{p}=2C\ cos(2t)-2B\ sin(2t)$$
$$y''_{p}= -4B\ cos(2t)-4C\ sin(2t)$$

Replace all in the original ODE

$$A+(2C-3B)\ cos(2t)-(2B+3C)\ sin(2t)={1\over2}-\frac 12\ cos(2t)$$

Therefore $A=\frac 12;\ \ \ 2C-3B=-\frac 12;\ \ \ 2B+3C=0\ $
$$A=\frac 12$$
$$B=\frac {3}{26}$$
$$C=-\frac {1}{13}$$

$$\mathbf{y_{p}(t)= \frac 12+\frac {3}{26}\ cos(2t)-\frac {1}{13}\ sin(2t)}$$

Our final Answer

$$\mathbf{y(t)=e^{{-{t\over 2}\ }}\left[C_{1}cos\left({\sqrt3\over2}t\right)+C_{2}sin\left({\sqrt3\over2}t\right)\right]+\frac 12+\frac {3}{26}\ cos(2t)-\frac {1}{13}\ sin(2t)}$$
OR
$$\mathbf{y(t)=e^{{-{t\over 2}\ }}\left[C_{1}cos\left({\sqrt3\over2}t\right)+C_{2}sin\left({\sqrt3\over2}t\right)\right]+\frac {1}{26}{\left[3cos(2t)-2sin(2t)+13\right]}}$$

Please tell me if something it's wrong.

Comment: Yes Thankyou so much I followed along and got exactly the same! :) youre amazing!

Comment: Ur welcome :) I love these things

Comment: It's `sin` not `sen`

Comment: I fixed it, anything else?

Comment: Use a backslash for `\sin ` and `\cos` and other named functions. Just a future tip

Comment: @Dylan ok thanks for the advice :)